# Visualise Lipschitz Equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, metric-spaces

I have a question on Lipschitz equivalence, defined in the following way:

> Let $X$ be a set, and let $d$ and $d'$ be metrics on $X$. We say that $d$ and $d'$ are Lipschitz equivalent if there exists real numbers $c,C>0$ such that for all $x,y \in X$,
>
> $$
> c d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) \leq C d(x,y)
> $$

I would like to know if it is sensible to visualise the equivalence as follows: let A be a space as seen under metric $d$. Then we can obtain the space A as seen under metric $d'$ by stretching and/or compressing the space by a finite amount. I am picturing it as the space being a giant 2-dimensional rubber surface that I can stretch and compress at will.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is sensible but there is one limitation in thinking about stretching rubber, which is that this viewpoint is mostly limited to *length* spaces, i.e., metric spaces where the distance is expressed as the infimum of lengths of curves joining a pair of points.  In other words, this is OK so long as you take rubber with a grain of salt.

For example, the unit circle has two natural metrics: (1) the Euclidean, where the distance between opposite points is $2$; and (2) the length metric, where the distance between opposite points is $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you elaborate a little bit on what is a non-length space?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your picture would rather refer to a situation where
$d'(x,y) = Kd(x,y)\ $ for some fixed $K > 0$.

The situation is a bit different in the case of the Lipschitz equivalence. Indeed, suppose for instance that $c = 1$ and $C = 3$. You may perfectly have three pairs of points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, $(x_3, y_3)$ such that $d'(x_1, y_1) = d(x_1, y_1)$, $d'(x_2, y_2) = 2d(x_2, y_2)$ and $d'(x_3, y_3) = 3d(x_3, y_3)$. Thus in some sense, your compression ratio may depend on the pair of points you choose.

Comment: I should have specified I was thinking that the space could be compressed in some parts which stretched in others. Either way, thanks for your answer!