# If absolute is for subtraction, is there anything for division?

Tags: absolute-value

$\mathrm{Abs}(a - b)$ is $b - a$ if $a - b < 0$ else $a -b$.

If so, is there anything equivalent for division? That is, something like:

$\mathrm{Xxx}(a/b)$ is $b/a$ if $a/b < 1$ else $a/b$.

Thanks.

Comment: For which $a,b$? Integers? Real numbers? $0<1$ for instance, how do you plan on dividing by it?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are real, and $b ≠ 0$ in the division case. Actually, I think setting $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ in the division case makes the discussion easy, but not sure very much.

Comment: Here's a function that does that operation $f(x)=x^\frac{x-1}{|x-1|}$

Comment: multiplicative inverse is there

Comment: For positive real numbers $a$ and $b,$ one sometimes wishes to consider $L=\max\{\frac{a}{b},\frac{b}{a}\}.$ For example, if you're dealing with a situation in which it is important to know that a certain variable quantity is bounded above zero and below infinity (e.g. the notion of [Lipschitz equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1974414/13130) and describing equivalent order of growth for functions), then we can describe this by the use of a single parameter by saying it's between $L^{-1}$ and $L$ for some positive number $L.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious formula for positive real $x$, equivalent to Asher2211's comment, is
$$
f(x) = e^{|\log x|}
= \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{x} & 0 < x < 1, \\
  x & 1 \leq x.
\end{cases}
$$
Conceptually, the natural logarithm $\log$ maps the positive reals to the reals (converting multiplication/division to addition/subtraction), the absolute value does its thing, and $\exp$ sends the value back to the positive reals (converting addition/subtraction back to multiplication/division).

This illustrates a useful general mathematical idiom, "transfer of structure".

This function can be extended to $f(x) = e^{|\log|x||}$, for non-zero real $x$, and $f(0) = 0$, i.e., $f(x) = 1/|x|$ if $0 < |x| < 1$ and $f(x) = |x|$ otherwise.

[image: A function analogous to absolute value for multiplication]

Comment: The "Conceptually" part is so helpful.